# NoClassDefFoundError with clojure tools logging

Tags: logging, clojure, log4j, noclassdeffounderror

I'm using clojure.tools.logging for a web application. For long times it works fine, with `org.clojure/tools.logging "0.1.2"`. I start and stop then re-start clojure repl[`lein repl`] for multiple time for development testing purposes. Suddenly, repl throws following error. I update the logging library to `org.clojure/tools.logging "0.2.3"`, but, no use. Still I get the same error, It only gave this error on the repl, but, with the application running, logs work fine. I coudn't identify where is the issue.

I'm using lo4j with clojure.tools.logging.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: clojure/tools/logging/impl/LoggerFactory (NO_SOURCE_FILE:0)
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Adding to :aot in the project.clj file worked for me.

```
:aot [clojure.tools.logging.impl ...]
```

Comment: Worked for me as well. Probably should be the accepted answer.

Comment: I can't get this to work when building and running an uberjar

Answer (score 7):

I would try lein clean, and then lein deps, and then lein compile and finally lein repl.  If that didn't work I'd next try manually deleting the lib and classes directories, and then run lein deps, lein compile and then lein repl again.

Comment: Yuck, is your code directly referencing clojure.tools.logging.impl.LoggerFactory? If so, find the clojure logging jar and open it as a zip archive, and look for the LoggingFactory class. If it exists, but is in a different package then update your code. If its not there, then you will have to research what to replace it with.  If your code doesn't reference it, and its not in the jar file, then its likely that there is a bug in the project, and you ought to ask the maintainers about it.

Comment: Also, can you post the dependencies from your project clj file?

Comment: The class file isn't in the logging jar, because LoggerFactory is a defprotocol.  It should be generated when impl.clj is read.

Comment: For me the problem was the order that the code was loaded in. Adding a directive that ahead of time compiles the clojure.tools.logging.impl namespace fixed my problem.

Comment: I just ran into a situation the other day where I had an issue in leiningen where I had two aot classes, one depended on the other, and I had the order specified incorrectly in the project.clj file. Depending on what was going on, sometimes I could get it to work and sometimes not. Once I realized what was wrong, I fixed the project.clj file and had no more problems.

Comment: still applies in 2016. I installed the re-frame template, and had this along with a clj-time related AOT error.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a old one, but I just ran into the same problem and apparently ~/.lein/profiles.clj was also having some sort of conflict with log4j. 
I've cleared it entirely and it started working.